# Color Filter For React Image Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there any way to add a color filter in React Native Image component ?

I tried using tintColor as a prop - That works well for single color images.

But for Multi Color Images - I need a separate filter.

Answer (score 0):

`gl-react-native` has all sorts of image effects that you can use in your app

https://github.com/ProjectSeptemberInc/gl-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
gl-react-native
```

But it has a limitation that it will not provide you an option to save the filtered image.

So my suggestion is to implement the filters in Native IOS and Android code and use native IOS and Android view in react native.

The solution is difficult but it works properly.